# Netsuite: Cant create access token with Administrator role

Tags: erp

I am trying to integrate a softphone application with Netsuite using token based authentication, but when I use a role created just for the TBA I am getting errors in the application. I see in some of our other access tokens they were set up with the Administrator role, but when I try to create a new token I do not have the option to select the Administrator role. How can I make an access token with the Administrator role?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy65k.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is frustratingly simple.

Rather than navigating 'Setup' -> 'Users' -> 'Access Tokens', you must go via the dashboard Settings portlet to 'Manage Access Tokens', then 'New My Access Token'.

This will apply the Administrator role if that's how you are currently logged in.

Comment: But integration with Admin role gives 400 Bad Request while authenticating with sandbox!, it worked with account id of production

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. Here are the permissions you need to add to any non Admin role.

Setting up Token Based Authentication roles

Token Based Authentication is a per user authentication and requires certain permissions in NetSuite. An existing role can be used (recommended) or a new role can be created.

The relevant role permissions are under the ‘Setup’ subtab. The following token-based authentication permissions can be added to non-administrator roles as appropriate.

Access Token Management

Users with this permission can create, assign, and manage tokens for any user in the company. Users with this permission cannot use token–based authentication to log in to the NetSuite UI.

Log in using Access Tokens

Users with this permission can manage their own tokens using the Manage Access Tokens link in the Settings portlet, and they can log in using a token.

User Access Tokens

Users with only this permission can log in using a token, that is, they can to use tokens to call a RESTlet. Users with only this permission cannot manage tokens or access pages where tokens are managed.